# How to make the south panel full width in DockLayoutPanel?

Tags: gwt

I am using the GWT DockLayoutPanel, as described in this post:

http://www.giantflyingsaucer.com/blog/?p=2302

There you can see that the north component fills the page width, but the south component is between the west and south.

Funny thing, as the GWT documentation example shows different:

https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/latest/images/DockLayoutPanel.png

(from https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideUiPanels)

Is it possible to get the south component to behave like the north component, filling the page width?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe it's strictly dependent on the order you add the panels: if you add the south panel before the west and east, it'll take the full width. If you add it after west but before east, it'll take all the width between west and the east side, but the east panel will be displayed above the south panel; etc.